# How can I change the color of the <title> of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the text and background color of the `<title>` of a web page? I would like to do this programatically from Javascript.

I would like it to work cross browser if possible.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of website that you think is doing this?

Comment: I have never seen this personally. I wasn't sure if it was possible as I didn't know how to search on web page title using google

Comment: Why the closing vote Peter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the title text colour or background. But what you can do is change the favicon (the image to the left of the title).

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

I know that's not what you asked, but maybe it's the next best thing?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is the next best thing

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The `<title>` tag controls the title of the window that the web browser shows. Its color is set by the operating system.